# More ergonomic/elegant way to use specific version of a package in Nix?

Tags: nix, nixos

I am trying to use specific versions of two packages:

- ruby 3.0.3
- postgresql 14.0.4

After hours of googling and experimenting, I came up with such a `shell.nix` file:

```hs
let
  # stable-22.05
  pkgs = import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/040c6d8374d090f46ab0e99f1f7c27a4529ecffd.tar.gz") {};

  # inludes postgres 14.0.4
  pgpkgs = import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/d86bcbb415938888e7f606d55c52689aec127f43.tar.gz") {};

  # includes ruby 3.0.3
  rubypkgs = import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/d1c3fea7ecbed758168787fe4e4a3157e52bc808.tar.gz") {};
in

pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    pgpkgs.postgresql_14

    rubypkgs.ruby_3_0
  ];
}
```

(used https://lazamar.co.uk/nix-versions to find a commit)

I am wondering if there is a better way for handling my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to define or use `pkgs`.  You can just get the `mkShell` function from `pgpkgs` (which seems like the better option since it's slightly newer than `rubypkgs`.

For the long term, I recommend fixing your project to work with the version of Ruby in commit `d86bcbb` and then just use that commit for everything, which is simpler than using multiple commits.

Another thing you should know is that you can use git to clone nixpkgs to somewhere on your computer, then use `git checkout d86bcbb` to check out the commit you are interested in.  Then set your `NIX_PATH` environment variable to make it so that `nixpkgs` refers to that commit:

```
export NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=/path/to/your/nixpkgs
```

Now you can use `import <nixpkgs>` in your expressions, and if you want to try a different commit you can just use the regular git commands for changing commits, without needing to use a text editor or deal with large hashes.  Also, the command `nix-shell -p ruby -p postgresql` uses  `NIX_PATH` to find its derivations.

Comment: yeah, I read about `NIX_PATH` but I am trying to achieve full reproducibility for other members of the team as well so the only thing required from them is just typing `nix-shell` in the command line and this approach kinda breaks it. and pkgs are just for other things I don't include in this question.